# Solve system of equations does not match

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following system of equations:

```
edges = ({
{1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0},
{0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0},
{1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0},
{1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0},
{0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1},
{0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 0, -1, 0},
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1},
{0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0},
{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, -1},
{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, -1}
});lf ={174.268, 174.268, 174.268, 278.04, 278.04, 278.04, 209.21, 209.21, \
209.21, 174.268, 174.268, 174.268};xf = {x1, -50, -50, x4, x5, x6}; yf = {y1, 
y2, -86.6025, y4, y5, y6}; zf = {0, 0, 0, z4, z5, 
z6}; lfsol = NSolve[
Table[lf[[i]] == 
Diagonal[\[Sqrt](DiagonalMatrix[(edges.xf)^2] + 
     DiagonalMatrix[(edges.yf)^2] + 
     DiagonalMatrix[(edges.zf)^2])][[i]], {i, 1, 12}], {x1, x4, 
x5, x6, y1, y2, y4, y5, y6, z4, z5, z6}, Reals]
```

The value of the unknown y2 can be directly found by solving the second equation of the system (i=2). However, by using such formulation the computational time seems to be very high.
If I evaluate y2 as above, that is:

```
y2f = Solve[lf[[2]] == Sqrt[(86.6025 + y2)^2], {y2}][[2]]
```

and I replace y2/.y2f in NSOlve, the feasible solution lfsol[[7]] (the feasibility of the solution is consistent with a problem that does not affect this question) does not match the value of y2.

Where is the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `NMinimize` to solve the problem

```
eqn = Table[lf[[i]] ==Diagonal[\[Sqrt](DiagonalMatrix[(edges.xf)^2] + DiagonalMatrix[(edges.yf)^2] + DiagonalMatrix[(edges.zf)^2])][[i]], {i, 1, 12}];

NMinimize[{1, eqn}, {x1, x4, x5, x6, y1, y2, y4, y5, y6, z4, z5, z6}]
(*{1., {x1 -> 100.921, x4 -> -97.7232, x5 -> 29.7027, x6 -> 68.9411,y1 -> 0.531502, y2 -> 87.6655, y4 -> 23.1858, y5 -> -95.6922,y6 -> 74.1009, z4 -> 193.219, z5 -> 193.219, z6 -> 193.219}}*)
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know why `NSolve` is slow but if you artificially raise precision on the input then it is reasonably fast.

```
vars = {x1, x4, x5, x6, y1, y2, y4, y5, y6, z4, z5, z6};
origexprs = 
  Sqrt[Diagonal[(DiagonalMatrix[(edges.xf)^2] + 
       DiagonalMatrix[(edges.yf)^2] + 
       DiagonalMatrix[(edges.zf)^2])]] - lf;
Timing[realsolns = 
   NSolve[SetPrecision[origexprs, 200], vars, Reals];]
Length[realsolns]

(* Out[4763]= {1.108, Null}

Out[4764]= 16 *)
```